SQLite throws exception during connection opening when SingleFile is true
I am trying to pack my app in a single file, but I keep getting this exception that kills my exe:
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1')

System.Private.CoreLib
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String connectionString, Boolean parseViaFramework)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at OrderManager.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Documents\GitHub\OrderManager\Program.cs:line 52

Which is nothing fancy:
51. File.AppendAllText(AppContext.BaseDirectory + @"\log.txt", ProgramParameters.connectionStringAdmin + Environment.NewLine);
52. connection = new(ProgramParameters.connectionStringAdmin);

I check for the content of ProgramParameters.connectionStringAdmin which is correct:
Data Source = C:\Users\Documents\GitHub\OrderManager\bin\Release\net6.0-windows10.0.22621.0\publish\db\ManagerOrdini.db ; cache=shared; synchronous  = NORMAL ;  journal_mode=WAL; temp_store = memory;  mmap_size = 30000000000; 

Debug and Release modes work as intended with no error.
My trial, beside some code testing, was to exclude the package from the .csproj file, but apparently it doesn't extend to packages:
<PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationIcon>icon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    
    <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    <_SuppressWinFormsTrimError>true</_SuppressWinFormsTrimError>
    <CustomResourceTypesSupport>true</CustomResourceTypesSupport>
    <BuiltInComInteropSupport>true</BuiltInComInteropSupport>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <CheckForOverflowUnderflow>true</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>
    <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
    <DebuggerSupport>true</DebuggerSupport>
    <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
    
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>

    </PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite" Version="1.0.118">
            <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
        </PackageReference>
    ...

Any other suggestion?

What happens if you set a breakpoint directly on Path.Combine - what are the actual parameter arguments you see?

@Dai with my current knowledge, I am not able to set a breakpoint on decompiled scode. Pretty sure that the code that is causing the problem is provided by the developers of SQLite.
I feel like(since the stacktrace is truncated), but I think that the line that is causing the problem is this one:ConfigureViaOneFile(Path.Combine(GetDirectory(DirectoryType.Configure), "sds-see.eagle"));  from the decompiled code.
Strangely, with net framework and Costura, I didn't have any problem.

As reported here, I added this at the end of the .csproj file:
<Target Name="ExplicitRemoveFromFilesToBundle" BeforeTargets="GenerateSingleFileBundle" DependsOnTargets="PrepareForBundle">
        <ItemGroup>
          <FilesToRemoveFromBundle Include="@(FilesToBundle)" Condition="$([System.String]::new('%(Filename)').ToLower().EndsWith('data.sqlite'))" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Message Text="FilesToRemoveFromBundle '@(FilesToRemoveFromBundle)'" Importance="high" />
        <ItemGroup>
          <FilesToBundle Remove="@(FilesToRemoveFromBundle)" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="CopyFilesToRemoveFromBundle" AfterTargets="Publish">
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToRemoveFromBundle)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)" />
        <Message Text="Copied files to remove from bundle to '$(PublishDir)'" Importance="high" />
    </Target>

Hope the way VS bundles doesn't lead to other rpoblems.
